# Scope property exists in child controller when it should not

Tags: angularjs

I have a child controller. In the parent controller `$scope.dealers` exist, but not in the child controller. How is it possible that `$scope.dealers` is existing in the child controller?

If you look in `watch` expression, you will see the `$scope.dealers` exist while in the `Closure` the `$scope` does not have dealers.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "feature" of angular scopes. Child scope prototypically inherits from the parent scope.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope - Scope Hierarchies section

> When Angular evaluates `{{name}}`, it first looks at the scope associated with the given element for the name property. If no such property is found, it searches the parent scope and so on until the root scope is reached. In JavaScript this behavior is known as prototypical inheritance, and child scopes prototypically inherit from their parents.

Answer (score 1):

A child controller will inherit the scope of it's parent. So if you define `$scope.dealers` in the parent scope, it will exist in the child scope as `$scope.dealers`.

Further, this can cause a lot of confusion, and as a general practice I try to avoid nesting controllers as much as possible. This is also why using the controller object itself is a better approach in many cases than using the scope.

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.dealers = [];  // this won't clash with parent scope
  //$scope.dealers = [];
});
```

And you can still reference this in your template:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="dealer in vm.dealers"></li>
</ul>
```

Check out the Angular style guides: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide